# windows phone 8 Interstitials

Tags: windows-phone-8, ads

Does anyone know a company providing full size ad interstitials for Windows Phone 8 (preferably with good fill rate)?
Banners are next to useless and I have done a search of the usual suspects (Chartboost, heyzap etc) to no avail. Most Windows Phone 7 Ad SDKs dont seem to work either

Answer (score 1):

MillenialMedia and InMobi have SDKS but they don't have inventory. ($0 eCPM for all countries)
LeadBolt doesn't have an SDK but you can embed URL for HTML Ad Overlay
Vserv has SDK and fill rate is good but SDK is in nascent stage and has several bugs

I have used all the four ad Networks and revenue is more or less same as banner ads

Comment: We have made various fixes to the Vserv SDK, any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Do reachout ravi @ vserv.mobi